# Whole site inner shadow overlay?

Tags: css

I'm redesigning my website and I want to apply an inner shadow to the background image. What is the best way to do this for a website?

I thought about applying a shadow in PS and then setting the background image to match the edge, but it never looks well around the edges.

My second idea was to apply a CSS box-shadow to the body tag, `box-shadow:inset 0 0 100px #000;`, but I know that box-shadows slow down the website rendering wise.

What would the be the best way to do this?

For reference, here are the two background images, the one without a shadow and with one.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8Wzj8s.png] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aldv0.jpg
[image: http://i.imgur.com/StVpOs.png] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDOfS.jpg

Comment: Have you considered a radial gradient? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Images for speed, but I'd use `box-shadow`. I'll leave IE8 to die.

Comment: Wouldn't for comparability's sake and the knowledge that it will look good on every device be better to just add the shadow in PS? Or is there some reason you cant do that? Maybe using transparent PNGs would help: http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000103.html#.TvLGf1QZvCM. It would be a shame if your hard work word turn out differently on 4 different browsers. (Of course, in the bright future this would not be a problem)

Comment: -kai It doesn't seem that I can get a radial gradient and image going. I could apply the shadow to an "overlay" div I suppose, I'll take a look. -saratis like I said, it's tough to achieve a nice effect around the edges where it fades in smoothly to the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using this code,

```
.overlay{
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
overflow-y:scroll;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px #000;
}
```

And my HTML looks like,

```
<body>
<div class="overlay">
Stuff...
</div>
</body>
```

The only problem with that is that without the `position:fixed` it would not be 100%, only 100% of the viewport. Making it fixed however, made it cover everything but you couldn't scroll, so adding `overflow-y:scroll` allows it to then scroll.